# Colour fill on matplotlib time series chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Consider the following pandas dataframe:

```
time                val server   state
2015-01-01 00:00:00 10   server01 normal
2015-01-01 00:02:00 18  server01 high
2015-01-01 00:03:00 41  server01 high
2015-01-01 00:04:00 22  server01 high
2015-01-01 01:05:00 32  server01 normal
2015-01-01 01:06:00 10  server01 high   
2015-01-01 01:07:00 42  server01 normal
2015-01-01 01:08:00 24  server01 normal
...........
```

When plotted on a time series chart, how to paint the area where `state = high` ?

Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you want to plot a span for the period with only one `'high'` state, you need to establish an artificial buffer to set above and below the max and min of each group respectively.

```
p = pd.Timedelta(30, unit='s')

df.val.plot()
for (state, _), g in df.groupby(['state', df.state.ne('high').cumsum()]):
    if  state == 'high':
        start = g.index.min() - p
        end = g.index.max() + p
        plt.axvspan(start, end, color='r', alpha=0.2)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. What about if I want to plot a span with say 2 different values: high, medium?